# Does avro support numeric constants for enum values, similar to protocol buffers enums?

Tags: protocol-buffers, avro

In Protobuf, I can use numeric values for enum constants.

```
  enum StatusEnum {
    UNKNOWN = 0;
    STARTED = 1;
    STOPPED = 2;
  }
```

Does `avro` support numeric values for enum constants in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the binary format an enum is encoded as the zero based position of the symbol in the symbol list, but any library you are using will figure out the actual symbol name and return that rather than the index number.

So no, avro doesn't support defining what numeric value the symbol will encode to.

Is there something you are trying to do with the numeric value?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have accidentally added a code sample involving aliases, and I modified the question and removed the alias references.
One more clarification, if I removed an existing symbol from an enum, would that cause problems when parsing old data, since the zero based positions of other elements have changed now?

Comment: Enums can have a `default` to handle this. See here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Enums

Suppose the writer has symbols FOO, BAR, and BAZ. You could make a reader schema with only BAR and BAZ that has a default to one of those symbols. Then if the previous data was written as FOO, the new reader will read it as the default value.